# adf.test vs ndiffs

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a really small time series dataset (21 yearly observations) and I want to check if my data is stationary.

`ndiffs(TS, test="adf")`

`[1] 2`

```
TSdiff2=diff(TS, differences=2)

adf.test(TSdiff2)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data: TSdiff2
Dickey-Fuller = -2.4232, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.4112
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

According to the explanation in this link [http://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-analysis-using-r-forecast-package/][1] : "*The null-hypothesis for an ADF test is that the data are non-stationary. **So large p-values are indicative of non-stationarity**, and **small p-values suggest stationarity**. Using the usual 5% threshold, **differencing is required** if the p-value is greater than 0.05.*

So it seems that my time series is not stationary despite the fact that I used the ndiffs function to estimate the number of differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `ndiffs` allows for at most second order differencing by default (argument `max.d=2`), see the [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/ndiffs). Perhaps that is why it returns 2 (which indicates order of **at least** 2).

Consider the following example: generate a series that is integrated of order 3 and find its order of integration using the function `ndiffs` using the default maximum order:

```
set.seed(1)
x=cumsum(cumsum(cumsum(rnorm(1000))))
ndiffs(x)
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=1))
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=2))
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=3))
```

It will suggest `2` for the raw series (incorrectly, and similarly to your case), `2` for the first difference of the series (correctly), `1` for the second difference (correctly) and `0` for the third difference (correctly).

Now allow for a greater maximum order of integration:

```
ndiffs(x,max.d=5)
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=1),max.d=5)
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=2),max.d=5)
ndiffs(diff(x,differences=3),max.d=5)
```

Now you are getting order `3` for the raw series, which is correct.

However, beware that economic and financial time series can rarely be argued to have an order of integration greater than 2 (this could be the motivation for the default value `max.d=2`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I allowed for a greater maximum in the max.d argument and now the ndiffs gives the right answer.